# Port server moxi on node X exited with status Y on Couchbase 1.8.1

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, .net, memcached, couchbase

I'm getting this error on live servers Win Server 2003 32 bit & 2008 64 bit.

```
Port server moxi on node 'ns_1@192.168.243.12' exited with status 3. Restarting. Messages: 2012-09-10 17:13:21: (cproxy_config.c.317) env: MOXI_SASL_PLAIN_USR (7)
2012-09-10 17:13:21: (cproxy_config.c.326) env: MOXI_SASL_PLAIN_PWD (9)
Assertion failed!

Program: d:\Program Files\Couchbase\Server\bin\moxi.exe
File: cproxy_protocol_b2b.c, Line 56

Expression: uc->noreply == false

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Seems that moxi.exe crashes or is terminated and restarts but caching stops working and requires iisreset to work again.
It started happening after new code release + windows updates + server restart so it's a bit hard to track down. It happens under normal load. Any idea